# paste text with a newline/return in formatted text

Tags: r, text, text-processing

I want to do a column that is formatted to use for a mailing address and I can not get the newline/return carriage or `<br/>` to work when making a new column.

```
name = c("John Smith", "Patty Smith", "Sam Smith")
address = c("111 Main St.", "222 Main St.", "555 C Street")
cityState = c("Portland, OR 97212", "Portland, OR 95212", "Portland, OR 99212")
df <- data.frame(name, address, cityState)
```

I want to create a column that formats the data in an address label:
    John Smith
    111 Main st.
    Portland, OR 97212

Each new column: will have a return after each line: so it is always 3 lines. One line for each of the other 3 columns.

```
# example of what I am trying to do... 
paste0(name, "return", address, "return", cityState).  Everything I have tried does not work for making a newline.
```

Comment: Use `'\n'` as a separator, and then use `cat` to see what you've actually got.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To get a new line (or return) we use `\n`. So

```
addr = paste(name,  address, cityState, sep="\n")
```

To view the result just use `cat`

```
> cat(addr[1])
#John Smith
#111 Main St.
#Portland, OR 97212
```

The function `cat` just prints to the screen.

---

The other standard character is `\t` for a tab-space.

Comment: It works for cat() but it may not work for some other functions. If this is the case, this should be used: as.character(paste(name,  address, cityState, sep="\n"))

Comment: How do you write text to a file without the  `\n`? Can you use `cat`?

Answer (score 12):

You need to paste it together with a newline (`\n`) separator. To assemble it from `df`,

```
addresses <- apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = '\n')
```

If you print it normally, it will show you the `\n` characters:

```
addresses
## [1] "John Smith\n111 Main St.\nPortland, OR 97212" 
## [2] "Patty Smith\n222 Main St.\nPortland, OR 95212"
## [3] "Sam Smith\n555 C Street\nPortland, OR 99212"
```

To print with the newlines evaluated use `cat`, also with `sep = '\n'` to insert line breaks between items:

```
cat(addresses, sep = '\n')
## John Smith
## 111 Main St.
## Portland, OR 97212
## Patty Smith
## 222 Main St.
## Portland, OR 95212
## Sam Smith
## 555 C Street
## Portland, OR 99212
```